# Typescript/AngularJS: $scope undefined outside of constructor

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope

How come I don't have scope for `$scope` outside of the constructor, unless I define my function using the fat arrow? Or is it possible to access $scope without defining a function using fat arrow?

```
namespace FooBar {
    export interface MyScope extends ng.IScope {
        message: string;
    }

    export class SandboxCtrl {
        static $inject = ["$scope", "$timeout"];
        private scope: MyScope;
        private timeout: ITimeoutService;
        constructor($scope: MyScope, $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
            this.scope = $scope;
            this.timeout = $timeout;
            timeout(this.foo, 1000); // does not work
            timeout(this.bar, 1000); // works
        }

        public foo() {
            this.scope.message = "foo bar"; // does not work
        }

        bar = () => {
            this.scope.message = "foo bar"; // works
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** I noticed I didn't shared the entire problem as I didn't knew it was because `$timeout` directive which causes the problem. Anyhow I updated my example.

Comment: did you add  DefinitelyTyped angualer files to you project ?

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper yes, I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into much details the problem is solved by using `bind` to bind `this` to the function.

```
timeout(this.foo.bind(this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `$scope` as a property in your controller class:

```
    export class SandboxCtrl {
        static $inject = ["$scope"];
        constructor(private $scope: MyScope) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're correct. I use it often, and the functions I declare are regular, no need for fat syntax. As far as I know, typescript deals with `this` inside functions - make sure the scope is the controller's.

Answer (score 0):

> timeout(this.foo, 1000); // does not work

This is be cause `foo` is an unbound function and the value of `this` will be driven by the caller.

Just use an arrow function

## More

This is covered here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html